Ubuntu Suspends when Second display ins switched to seperate input
Ubuntu 24.04
I have my laptop hooked up to two displays (while the laptop itself is closed),for clarity Monitor A and Monitor B, Monitor A is the primary display, Monitor B is hooked up to a switch that allows swaps it's input to a different machine.  If I switch the input from Ubuntu on B to the second source, the OS goes into suspend mode on mmonitor A.  Oddly enough if I open a video on full screen on youtube on Monitor A it prevents this. Is there any way to always have the primary display stay on when the second monitor has the input swapped.
